# Корень в слове "близкий"

Tags: морфемика, морфемный-разбор

В Морфемно-орфографическом словаре. — М.: АСТ.
Тихонов А. Н. 2002​: корень  **близк/ий**.

То же и здесь: Тихонов А. Н. Морфемно-орфографический словарь. — М.: Шк.-пресс, 1996.

Кто-нибудь сможет объяснить, почему **к** входит в корень?
Ср. родственые слова: приблизиться, близость, ближайший, ближний.

Есть и другие слова в издании 1996 г.: рез**к**/ий,низ**к**/ий, ред**к**/ий,  мяг**к**/ий, но скольз/**к**/ий.

В издании 2002 г. этих слов нет.

Comment: _Серж: В издании 2002г. этих слов нет._ === **Не может этого быть!**

Comment: – slava1947, я проверял на академике. Не нашел. Только слово близкий есть.

Comment: А разве на _Академике_ этот словарь (Тихонов А. Н. Морфемно-орфографический словарь. — М.: АСТ., 2002) выложен?

Comment: Да! Сейчас посмотрю, может смогу дать ссылку.

Comment: http://morphem_ru.academic.ru/

Comment: Так каких слов-то нет в словаре, на который Вы дали ссылку? По-моему, всё из перечисленного Вами выше я в нём нашёл.

Comment: slava1947, из всех слов,что я представил, мне удалось найти только слово ***близкий***.

Comment: _Серж: из всех слов,что я представил, мне удалось найти только слово **близкий**._ ===  ЧуднО!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> В Морфемно-орфографическом словаре. — М.: АСТ. Тихонов А. Н. 2002 :
>   корень ***близк***/ий.
>
> ...Почему ***к*** входит в корень?

Потому что Тихонов не нашёл глагола или существительного, от которого с помощью суффикса *-**к**(ий)* можно было бы образовать слово ***близкий***. У него оно в "Словообразовательном словаре русского языка" (М., 1990) —  непроизводное, от него образованы с усечением ***-к*** и *близ-ость*, и *ближ-н-ий*, и *близ-и-ть-ся*…

Но сказать, что Тихонов всегда  придерживался такого разбора, не могу. К примеру, в вышедшем под его редакцией "Словаре-справочнике по русскому языку" (М., 1997) суффикс в слове *близкий* выделен: *близ/**к**/ий*.

То же и в последнем по времени создания тихоновских словарей  —  "Комплексном словаре русского языка", вышедшем в 2005 году:

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
>
> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

У меня есть бумажный "Школьный словообразовательный словарь Тихонова". Там слова размещены по гнездам, и прилагательное "близкий" образует такое гнездо. Записано оно следующим образом: бли**з**к(ий), то есть З выделено жирным шрифтом. Далее обозначены цепочки: близкий - близость - поблизости; близкий - вблизи; близкий - ближний и т.д.

В этом семействе родственных слов **исходным** (главным) является прилагательное "близкий", которое имеет **основное смысловое** значение: находящийся, происходящий неподалёку, на небольшом расстоянии (противоп.: далёкий).

Все остальные слова - это или формы этого слова (ближе), или производные слова (близость), при образовании которых происходит **усечение корня и чередование** согласных, то есть корень имеет несколько морфов: БЛИЗК/БЛИЗ/БЛИЖ.

Это один подход к проблеме. В другом варианте можно бы считать, что близкий - это **непроизводное слово, но при этом основа его сложная (состоит из корня БЛИЗ и суффикса К).** Практически этот суффикс сохраняет только наречие "близко", в остальных случаях он усекается.

Comment: Но тогда прилагательное от чего образовано? И как мы узнаем,что это прилагательное,если суффикс не выделяется?

Comment: У Тихонова есть такое понятие, как словообразовательное гнездо.В основе строения гнёзд лежит принцип иерархии, принцип последовательного подчинения одних единиц другим. Главным словом в таком гнезде может быть существительное, прилагательное, глагол.  Я считаю, что в приведенном примере гнездо образует прилагательное (другие части речи просто отпадают). Не будете же вы, к примеру, считать, что все родственные слова  (по цепочке) образованы от существительного близость. А усечение основы - это очень распространенное явление, например: бегать - бег, усечение на глагольный суффикс.

Comment: Но словарь называется Морфемно-орфографический. Но ведь слово близкий образовано от сущестительного. Почему это не учитывается?

Comment: От какого существительного?

Comment: Близость. В слове "бег" нулевой суффикс.

Comment: Серж, если вы откроете словарь Кузнецова, то увидите в самом конце статьи существительное "близость", которое  мотивируется прилагательным близкий. Близость - это нахождение на близком расстоянии. Или вы будете считать, что близкий  мотивируется близостью, и какое тогда  дадите определение? Хорошо, что  бег имеет нулевой суффикс, а куда глагольный суффикс девался?  Словообразовательная цепочка: бегать - бег? И близкий - близость.

Comment: @ Arina,тема нулрвого суффикса тема немнога длинная, в коментариях все не уместишь. Об этом прочитайте у Литниевской. Тема: Морфемика.

Comment: По поводу близкий. Близкий - ближний. "Н" суффикс или корень? У Тихонова - суффикс. Почему в однокоренном слове к изчезает? Если бы ***к*** была бы корнем, должно было быть чередование в корне - к/н. Н входило бы в корень.

Comment: Н - суффикс, основа усекается на  К, чередования нет. Суть проблемы в том, что НЕПРОИЗВОДНАЯ  основа фактически является СЛОЖНОЙ и состоит из корня БЛИЗ и суффикса К, характерного для прилагательного. Отсюда  два решения, два разных подхода, так и будут возникать вопросы, пока не решится: можно ли непроизводную основу считать сложной?  У Тихонова слово "низкий"  также имеет корень НИЗК-, там же все глаголы (занизить, понизить),  а существительное "низ"  образует свое гнездо.

Comment: Да, у Тихонова низк- корень. Но: скольз/к/ий. К - суффикс. Почему в одном слове тот же суффикс выделяет, другой нет?

Comment: Arina, прочитал доплнение к вашему ответу. Если производная основа близкий, то можно ли в нем не выделять суффикс?

Comment: В том-то и вопрос, а кто на него ответит? Мне кажется, что можно, потому что у нас  морфемный анализ часто почему-то зависит от словообразовательного, а это разные предметы. Думаю, что при морфемном анализе можно разделить сложную непроизводную основу и выделить суффикс К, как типичный суффикс прилагательного. И про "скользкий": У Тихонова исходным является не прилагательное, а глагол скользить.

Comment: Да, по поводу того, почему морфемный анализ надо выпонять в неразрывной связи со словообразовательным, подробно написано у Литниевской. Я задам этот вопрос Грамоте, правда, неуверен, что ответят.